# JPA native query on Hibernate for distinct on column

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa

How to distinct on column with fk.
DB: postgres.

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT DISTINCT ON (a.fk_id), a.* FROM Appointment a WHERE a.fk_id IN (:ids)")
                .getResultList()
```

Error: SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

but on jdbc it works.

Comment: Why are you using  DISTINCT ON (a.fk_id) instead of DISTINCT (a.fk_id)

Comment: it can return all fields for Appointment class. But simple Distinct return only a.fk_id as Long class.

Answer (score 0):

The question has "sql" tag????

```
@Aysnc
@Query(
        value =
                "exec(:asdf)",
        nativeQuery = true)
List<String> somemethodforthat(String asdf);
List<String> serw = abc.somemethodforthat("SELECT DISTINCT "+col+" FROM temp_res");
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove comma, from query between (a.fk_id) and a.*
TRY:
`SELECT DISTINCT ON (a.fk_id) a.* FROM Appointment a WHERE a.fk_id IN (:ids)`
and try. I think, it will work.